# automapper boolean properties to yes or no

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-2

For a mapping between TypeA and TypeB i would like all the boolean properties to be mapped to 'Yes' or 'No'.
I don't want to override the `<bool, string>` mapping since i want that just for the mapping between TypeA and TypeB.
And I would not like to use .ForMember for each TypeA's boolean property since they are a lot.
Maybe there is a trick with ForAllMembers but I cannot make it works.

Comment: Where are you going to use the "Yes / No", only for display purposes, reporting, etc?

Comment: Displaying in a web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried adding a mapper between Bool and String and registering it in the engine? It may be that simple, but I don't remember.

you could also create a ValueConverter and then inform the mappings to use the converter. It's been awhile since i used AM, but this sounds about right.